# truncate and insert within procedure don't work together

Tags: oracle, dynamic, plsql

I need to do truncate table and then insert data in that table using procedure.

However, one does like dinamic sql but the other one doesn't:

```
create or replace 
procedure   RECREATE_AGGREGATE
AUTHID DEFINER
AS
BEGIN
    TRUNCATE TABLE AGGREGATE;    
    INSERT INTO AGGREGATE SELECT * FROM OLD_AGGREGATE;
END;
```

Error(6,14): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "TABLE" when expecting one of the following:     := . ( @ % ; The symbol ":= was inserted before "TABLE" to continue.

If I add `execute immediate` around `TRUNCATE` statement, it works fine, but insert is erroring out.
If I remove it, TRUNCATE TABLE complains...

```
create or replace 
    procedure   RECREATE_AGGREGATE
    AUTHID DEFINER
    AS
    BEGIN
        execute immediate 'TRUNCATE TABLE AGGREGATE';    
        INSERT INTO AGGREGATE SELECT * FROM OLD_AGGREGATE;
    END;
```

Error(7,5): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
    Error(7,84): PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Can some shed some light here?

Comment: try using execute immediate around the truncate statement.  This should not affect your insert (which may have other issues, but you'd need to post the error code).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
create or replace 
procedure   RECREATE_AGGREGATE
AUTHID DEFINER
AS
BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE AGGREGATE';    
    INSERT INTO AGGREGATE SELECT * FROM OLD_AGGREGATE;
END;
```

will work assuming that you have appropriate privileges.

Based on your edit (and echoing @OracleUser's comment), you're likely getting an error running your `INSERT` statement because `old_aggregate` is owned by another user and you only have `SELECT` privileges on that table via a role.  If you want to do something in a definer's rights stored procedure, you'll need to have those privileges granted directly to you (or be using 12c which lets you grant privileges to blocks of code rather than to users).

Assuming you want to use a definer's rights stored procedure, you'd need the owner of `old_aggregate` (or the DBA) to

```
GRANT SELECT 
   ON old_user.old_aggregate
   TO new_user;
```

You can verify that you only have the privilege via a role by disabling roles for the session.  I'll wager that if you do

```
SQL> set role none;
SQL> SELECT * FROM old_aggregate
```

that you'll get an ORA-00942 error as well.  This is a good way of simulating what privileges will be available to the user inside a definer's rights stored procedure.

Comment: i already knew this. what other privileges would I need. because right now, this is not working... :( Error(6,14): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "TABLE" when expecting one of the following:     := . ( @ % ; The symbol ":= was inserted before "TABLE" to continue.

Comment: @Angelina - What user owns each of the two tables?  What user owns the procedure?  What is the actual code you're running that generates this error?  The error message doesn't make a lot of sense given the code.

Comment: Cove: the AGGREGATE is owned by the same user the procedure is called by (caller_user). (caller_user) has select privileges on OLD_AGGREGATE . that's what makes no sense, because if I run it outside of procedure this works perfectly. maybe the privileges are not present when within the procedure...?

Comment: @Angelina I hope you privilges to that table, via a role. When called from a procedure, the privileges has to be given the use directly.

Comment: @Angelina - I updated my answer.  I believe OracleUser is spot on-- you probably have the privileges only via a role, not via the necessary direct grant.

Comment: I did this after setting role to NONE, and got different message this time: Error: ORA-01031: insufficient privileges. Now I am waiting for my DBA to give me some priviledges. Thanks @Justin Cove

Answer (score 0):

"TRUNCATE is DDL (data definition language). You cannot perform DDL from within PL/SQL. "
http://www.orafaq.com/forum/t/119427